# Что написать на React что бы получить больше практики?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, reactjs

Всем привет! В условиях карантина, нету возможности пойти на совбес и где-то начать работать. Но есть время что бы учить что-то новое. На данный момент, моя цель = React Developer. И вот я не знаю что мне сейчас учить или же что написать для получения опыта.

Мои знания(где-то минимальные, где-то более продвинутые): HTML5, CSS (bootsrap 4, grid), JS, React + разные маленькие библиотеки и фреймворки. Такие вещи как ToDoList, MovieSearcher, WeatherForecast уже писал, даже социальную сеть (за курсом на ютубе) писал. (+ много чего разного читал, смотрел, практиковал).

Может кто-то знает сайты с интересными API(главное что бы нормальная документация была)?

И вообще, кто опытный, кто шарит в новых технологиях, что учить, что смотреть, что писать? Что нужнее и важнее знать Junior разработчику? В интернете очень много всего, но учить все сразу, думаю, нету смысла. Хотелось бы стать опытным специалистом в одном направлении, а уже дальше, с годами развиватся все шире и шире.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возьми свой готовый небольшой проект и добавь в него:
0. Typescript
1. SASS
2. Route
3. MobX
4. fetch/promise (думаю уже используешь)
5. Навигация с помощью клавиатуры (это капец просто)

Comment: 0 Вот тоже думал посмотреть, 1. Нужно будет почитать подробнее, 2. Уже использовал, 3. Использовал Redux, есть ли смысл использовать MobX? 4. Конечно 5. Знаю))

Comment: Нужно кроме Redux знать как пишут функциональные компоненты, и на мой взгляд MobX нужен чтобы в целом понимать как выглядит проект в стиле mvc на реакте.